# Reason to specify first generic type

Tags: scala, generics, syntax

I have a question about generic functions in Scala.  Suppose I have a simple function like this (contrived example):

```
def subList[A](list:List[A], start:Int, elementCap:Int): List[A] ={
```

why does it require the first `[A]` ? as in why can't I have the signature

```
def subList(list:List[A], start:Int, elementCap:Int): List[A] ={
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because any time in a programming language that you reference a *variable* of whatever sort, you need to define it somewhere. *A* is a parametric type, which is to say it's like a variable but it refers to a type. A is not a constant, that's to say known for some other context, so it needs a definition.

It's actual value will be supplied concretely when the method is actually called.